# How to expand div that goes over other divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As you can see in demo if you hover on div, it will expand down then you can see more text but there will be a space between two rows.

How can I expand the divs that they go over other divs on second row?

Thanks in advance

Demo you can find here: https://codepen.io/rahman23/pen/LYGyzqb

and HTML/CSS code:

```
<section>

  <div class="services-grid row">
    <div class="service service1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 first">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
      <h3>My Jobs</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Weiterlesen <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="service service2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 first">
      <i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
      <h3>Further Education</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat. </p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Read More<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="service service3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 first">
      <i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i>
      <h3>Salary</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Read More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="service service1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 first">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
      <h3>New Opportunities</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Read More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="service service2">
      <i class="fas fa-book-reader"></i>
      <h3>Weiterbildung</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy. </p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Read More <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="service service3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 first">
      <i class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i>
      <h3>Salary Adjustment</h3>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy.</p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Read More<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

section {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #002776;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin: 0.4rem 0;
}

.section-lead {
  margin: 1rem auto 1.5rem;
}

.service a {
  color: #5b7abb;
  display: block;
}

.service h4 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #56ceba;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0.2rem;
}

.services-grid {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}

.service {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.service:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.service i {
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.service1 i,
.service1 h4,
.service1 .cta {
  color: #002776;
}

.service1:hover {
  border: 2px solid #002776;
}

.service2 i,
.service2 h3,
.service2 .cta {
  color: #002776;
}

.service2:hover {
  border: 2px solid #002776;
}

.service3 i,
.service3 h3,
.service3 .cta {
  color: #002776;
}

.service3:hover {
  border: 2px solid #002776;
}

.service .cta span {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.service > * {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.service .cta {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  .services-grid {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.cta i {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.cta {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.service p {
  max-height: 50px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.service:hover p {
  max-height: 150px;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.service:hover .service {
  background: #fbf9f9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I stripped it down to basics, but is this what you're after?

```css
div {
  width:400px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}  

li {
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  position:relative;
}
li > div {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
    border:1px solid #d9d9d9
}
li:hover > div{
  height:100px;
      position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
        Item
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Item
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Item
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Item
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Item
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        Item
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes but when I add position:relative for section and services grid in my code and position:absolute for service div:hover it does not work like in your demo

Comment: Sorry, that's the best I can do right now without sieving through your code. Bootstrap never does any favours when it comes to making edits unfortunately.